# How to binding previewTemplate to dropzone-wrapper in my template component

Tags: angular, angular-cli, dropzone

I have a form with a div and an image where the user's current photo is.
I created an icon at the top of the image which, when clicked, activates the dropzone directive and opens the box to choose a new photo.

The problem is that when selecting the photo, a dynamic div is generated by the drop zone itself, as the documentation explains.
I want the image to be reloaded in the image and in the template I've already created. I'm trying to use the previewTemplate but this is not what I want, I do not want to create a new template and I want the image to be reloaded inside my div with the current image. It's possible? How can I bind an id in previewTemplate to reference my div with an image that already exists to only change the src of the image?

I'm using angular version 8.

Example:

```html
<div fxLayout="column" >
   <img [src]='assets/images/{{photo}}.jpg' />
   <mat-icon class="material-icons" [dropzone]="config" 
      (init)="onUploadInit($event)" color="primary">photo_camera
   </mat-icon>
</div>
```

Component:

```ts
public config: DropzoneConfigInterface = {
 clickable: true,
 maxFiles: 1,
 autoReset: null,
 errorReset: null,
 cancelReset: null,
 previewTemplate: ?
};
```

I made an example in stackblitz. When you select the photo from your computer, dropzone generates a dynamic div with the selected image and effects. What I wanted, is that the image of the dog was changed to the new image inside the img, next to the effects of the dropzone:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvvw3w

Comment: Hi, Jéssica, welcome to SO! For community it would be easier to help you if you could provide a simple example that reproduces the problem. You could add a code snippet to your answer or create a shareable project using 3rd party service, like [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com). Also, I assume that theres a missing closing `</mat-icon>` tag in your code — please, add it via editing your question.

Comment: Hi Kos! I set an example in stackblitz to demonstrate the example. The <mat-icon> tag is actually unclosed, but that's not the problem, my code is correct. In the example of stackblitz you will see that when selecting a photo it generates a dynamic div with the selected photo, what I wanted was for the image of the dog to be changed to the image that you selected with the success effects of dropzone. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uvvw3w